# AWS IoT Connection error : Invalid "caCert" option supplied with aws-iot-device-sdk

Tags: aws-sdk, mqtt, iot, aws-iot, self-signed-certificate

I've provisioned a device in AWS with device Certificate which is signed by my CA. Also, I've registered my CA along with verificationCert in AWS previously.

Now when I send the data, In the options,

```
var awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');
var device = awsIot.device({
privateKey: '--BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY--', //private key of my device
clientCert: '--BEGIN CERTIFICATE --', //cat deviceCertificate and registered CA 
caCert: '--BEGIN CERTIFICATE--', //Amazon root CA
clientId: 'Thing01',
region: 'us-west-2',
host: xxxxxxxx.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com,
secretKey: 'dcvevv',
accessKeyId: 'ferferer'
});

device.on('connect',function(err){
device.publish('$aws/things/Thing01/shadow/update',JSON.stringify({
"state" :{
  "desired": {
 "color": "blue"
 }
}
})
);
})
```

I'm getting below error

throw new Error(exceptions.INVALID_CA_CERT_OPTION); ^ Error: Invalid "caCert" option supplied.

Can anyone let me know where I'm doing wrong in the above code snippet?

Edit1: 
After making corrections in the options, below is the code:

```
    var awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');
    var device = awsIot.device({
    host:'xxxxx.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
    keyPath : './certs/deviceTest/5e2570c0605418.key',  
    certPath : './certs/deviceTest/5e2570c0605418AndCA.crt',   //cat of device and Registered CA
    caPath : './certs/rootCA.pem', //public cert of AWS root CA1 
    clientId: 'ManualDevice_01', //ThingName
    region : 'us-west-2',
   secretKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
   accessKeyId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  }); 
   console.log("Invoking on connect");
   device.on('connect',function(error ){
    console.log("In on connect !!");
    if(error)
       console.log('could not connect');
  device.publish('$aws/things/ManualDevice_01/shadow/update',JSON.stringify({
  "state" : {
    "desired" : {
        "color" : "pink",
        "power" : "off",
        "val":"1"
     }
    }
   } ), function(err){
   if(err)
      console.log("Could not send : Error : "+err)
   else
   {
      console.log("Sent data")
   } 
   }
  );
 console.log('Message sent........')
 })
 device.on('message',function(topic,payload){
     console.log('message',topic,payload.toString());
  })
```

The statements inside device.on('connect') are not getting executed.
I could see only "Invoking on connect" being printed

Edit 2: Issue is resolved!!!

While creating a device, I have to attach Policy to it.
Then I'm able to send the data in above specified way through MQTT with certificates.

Comment: Also, I'm not sending https in the host.

Comment: Are you sure it wants the actual certificates and not a path to the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [doc](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js#device-class) implies you should be passing paths to the files for the TLS certificate's and key.

e.g.

```
var device = awsIot.device({
   keyPath: <YourPrivateKeyPath>,
  certPath: <YourCertificatePath>,
    caPath: <YourRootCACertificatePath>,
  clientId: <YourUniqueClientIdentifier>,
      host: <YourCustomEndpoint>
});
```

Later on in the same [doc](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js#awsiotdeviceoptions) it says `caCert` can be a buffer (not a String)

> - `caCert`: same as caPath, but can also accept a buffer containing CA certificate data

This means you will need to decode the string value first.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61161984/edit) the question to add technical detail (e.g. code) do not try and include it in the  comments. You can't just use `Buffer.from()` You need something that understand PEM or DER encoding

Comment: Hi hardillb, thanks for the quicker response. The reason I went with caCert,clientCert and privateKey is that I was facing the same issue i-e not being able to execute the statements inside device.on('connect'). Otherwise, caPath,certPath and privatekeyPath is comfortable for me.  Could you suggest the way with AWS IoT MQTT sending data with certificates. i'll edit my answer and place the code i used earlier. Correct me if I'm doing wrong anywhere

Comment: It worked now!! I used buffer only. But I forgot to attach a policy to the certificate when I register a device. Thanks hardillb.

Answer (score 0):

I did it as follow:

```
 const caCert = process.env.caCert
const privateKey = process.env.privateKey
const cert = process.env.cert

const device = AWSIoT.device({
    privateKey: Buffer.from(privateKey),
    clientCert: Buffer.from(cert,),
    caCert: Buffer.from(caCert),
    clientId: '123456789',
    host: process.env.endPoint,
    // other options
})
```